# Installing PIG on single node

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

I installed Hadoop (1.0.2) for a single node on Windows 7 with Cygwin, and it is working. However, I cannot get PIG (0.10.0) to see the Hadoop.

```
1) "Error: JAVA_HOME is not set."
```

I added this line to pig (under bin): export JAVA_HOME=/cygdrive/c/PROGRA~1/Java/jdk1.7.0_05

```
2) which: no hadoop in (/usr/local/b.....)
cygpath: cannot create short name of C:\pig-0.10.0\logs
Cannot locate pig.jar. do 'ant jar', and try again
```

I tried adding below lines to pig and it is still not finding hadoop. What should i do?

```
export PIG_HOME="/cygdrive/c/pig-0.10.0"
export PATH=$PATH:$PIG_HOME/bin
export PIG_CLASSPATH=/cygdrive/hadoop/hadoop-1.0.2/conf
```

Answer (score 2):

You might need to add your Hadoop install to your path as well. e.g.

```
export HADOOP_INSTALL=/Users/yourname/dev/hadoop-0.20.203.0 
export PATH=$PATH:$HADOOP_INSTALL/bin
```

Answer (score 2):

I had same issue with pig-0.11. Seems this is cygwin specific issue.

Copying pig-0.11.1-withouthadoop to pig-withouthadoop.jar under PIG_HOME fixed the issue for me

Comment: Sudhir, I have added pig-0.10.1-withouthadoop.jar to under PIG_HOME but it does not solve the issue. I keep on getting the same error : "Cannot locate pig-withouthadoop.jar. do 'ant jar-withouthadoop', and try again"             my .bashprofile looks like this :          export HADOOP_HOME=/c/Hadoop
export PIG_HOME=/c/PIG
export PATH=$PATH:$HADOOP_HOME/bin
export PATH=$PATH:$PIG_HOME/bin

Comment: I tried renaming "pig-0.10.1-withouthadoop.jar" to "pig-withouthadoop" then also I am facing the same issues. Any help on this will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I was trying to set up PIG on my gateway machine which has Windows 7 installed on it.

This issue is very specific to Cygwin.

After breaking my head for a couple of hours I found the solution :

Solution is very simple.

Just rename the jar file under   ”pig-0.10.1-withouthadoop.jar” to “pig-withouthadoop.jar”.

Its documented [here](http://hadooptips.wordpress.com/2013/08/01/cannot-locate-pig-jar-do-ant-jar-and-try-again/)

Answer (score 0):

Also, you can add path : (hadoop directory)\hadoop-v.v.v\bin to environment variables manually in Windows 7. This will solve this problem

```
which: no hadoop in (/usr/local/b.....)
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with Pig 0.12.0 (and Hadoop 1.0.3) installed on Fedora 19.
When trying any Pig command, e.g.

```
pig -help
```

I was getting the error:

```
Cannot locate pig-withouthadoop.jar. do 'ant jar-withouthadoop.jar', and try again
```

Hadoop and Pig installation /bin folders were properly included in my PATH.

Simply copying **pig-0.12.0-withouthadoop.jar to PIG_HOME** folder fixed the issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

You must visit this for installing pig 12 on hadoop 2.2.0 without any errors as it re compiles the pig library for hadoop version specified.

http://javatute.com/javatute/faces/post/hadoop/2014/installing-pig-11-for-hadoop-2-on-ubuntu-12-lts.xhtml

After following the steps, you will get the running pig without any errors on grunt.

Just enjoy doing.

```
% pig [return]
```